# Interpolation binding not updated on child components

Tags: angular, interpolation, angular-routing

Any code written on the children of a child component does not update when updating the interpolation variable

I'm just trying to update a variable constantly like this

```
counter: number = 10;
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
      console.log(this.counter)
    }, 5000);
  }
```

and then in the html
`{{counter}}}`

My app-routing.module.ts

```
  { path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      children:[
      {
        path: '',
        component: CustomerListComponent
      },{
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children:[
          {
            path: 'hchild',
            component: HChildComponent,
            children:[
              {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'hchildTab1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
              },
              {
                path: 'hchildTab1',
                component: HChildTab1Component
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'logs',
        component: LogsComponent
      }
  ]},

  { path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
      children:[
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
  ]},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now the code works fine on all the components except the hchild, hchildtab1, hchildtab2
The value on the HTML just remains as 10 and does not update only on these 3 child components.

Could someone help me with what I'm missing?
My angular version is 11.1.2

Comment: please check component are define in main module

Comment: Everything is defined and everything works well, except the variable being updated. It just shows the constant value and never changes only on those three child components I mentioned

Comment: You may need to `bind(this)`, so the timeout callback knows the context of `this`.